# How can I get the element by selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha, captcha

How can i get the recaptcha data-sitekey by selenium on this websie?

https://premier.hkticketing.com/

I have try this code:

```
data_sitekey = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "g-recaptcha"))).get_attribute("data-sitekey")
print(data_sitekey)
```

or

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, "g-recaptcha")))
```

also return Unable to locate element
How can I get the data-sitekey to bypass recaptcha?

Comment: Is that precisely the correct URL of the class name?

Comment: That frame is itself in another iframe. Review HTML carefully. Swiitch to the first one, wait a little, switch to the next one, wait again, search for the element and iti will be there.Oh, and make sure your selectors are correct.